# two finite models of complete orderings are elementary equivalent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

let M , N be finite simple orderings. prove that M and N satisfy exactly the same universal sentences.

I know for two finite models if they are elementary equivalent they would be isomorphic, I don't know if I can use this fact to prove this problem or not.

Comment: Does "simple/complete ordering" mean "linear/total ordering"?

Comment: yes(complete ordering or linear ordering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: replacing "finite" with "infinite," the statement is true, and follows from the more general fact

> If $\mathcal{M}$ is a relational structure and $\varphi$ is a universal sentence true of $\mathcal{M}$, then every finite substructure $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ has $\mathcal{A}\models\varphi$

and the particular feature of linear orders that

> Any two infinite linear orders have the same finite suborders.

(In the context of finite non-relational languages, replace "finite" with "finitely generated" in the first fact above; the point is that "finite" = "finitely generated" when there are only relation symbols in the language.)

---

The statement is extremely false as stated. Let $L_n$ be the unique up to isomorphism linear order with $n$ elements. Then "$\forall x, y(x=y)$" is true in $L_1$ but not $L_2$.

And this just keeps going: e.g. "$\forall x_1, ..., x_{17}(\bigvee_{i<j<18}x_i=x_j)$"  is true in $L_{16}$ but not $L_{17}$.

Note that these are even *positive* universal formulas, and that this has nothing to do with the order structure.

Comment: please take a look at the problem 1.4.20 of chang keisler's book  3rd edition (model theory).

Comment: @msionl I don't have access to that book at the moment. Do you understand why what I've written above is a counterexample to the question *as stated* in your question? (Or maybe I'm missing something?)

Comment: The question in C and K says infinite linear orders satisfy the same universal sentences.

Comment: oh,sorry it is infinite.... i was wrong... thanks a lot

Comment: I think the fact you want is that a structure satisfies and universal sentence iff *every* finite substructure satisfies the sentence.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Derp, yes, fixed.